Duplicate null columns created during pivot in polars
I have this example dataframe in polars:
df_example = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "DATE": ["2024-11-11", "2024-11-11", "2024-11-12", "2024-11-12", "2024-11-13"],
        "A": [None, None, "option1", "option2", None],
        "B": [None, None, "YES", "YES", "NO"],
    }
)

Which looks like this:




DATE
A
B




0
2024-11-11




1
2024-11-11




2
2024-11-12
option1
YES


3
2024-11-12
option2
YES


4
2024-11-13

NO



As you can see this is a long format dataframe. I want to have it in a wide format, meaning that I want the DATE to be unique per row and for each other column several columns have to be created. What I want to achieve is:




DATE
A_option1
A_option2
B_YES
B_NO





2024-11-11
Null
Null
Null
Null



2024-11-12
True
True
True
Null



2024-11-13
Null
Null
Null
True



I have tried doing the following:
df_example.pivot(
    index="DATE", on=["A", "B"], values=["A", "B"], aggregate_function="first"
)

However, I get this error:
DuplicateError: column with name 'null' has more than one occurrence

Which is logical, as it tries to create a column for the Null values in columns A, and a column for the Null values in column B.
I am looking for a clean solution to this problem. I know I can impute the nulls per column with something unique and then do the pivot. Or by pivoting per column and then dropping the Null columns. However, this will create unnecessary columns. I want something more elegant.

I ended up with:
(
    df_example.pipe(
        lambda df: df.group_by("DATE").agg(
            [
                pl.col(col).eq(val).any().alias(f"{col}_{val}")
                for col in df.select(pl.exclude("DATE")).columns
                for val in df.get_column(col).unique().drop_nulls()
            ]
        )
    ).sort("DATE")
)



pl.DataFrame.pivot().
pl.element(), pl.Expr.is_not_null() and pl.Expr.any() to convert values to true / false.
pl.DataFrame.drop() drop columns with only nulls.
pl.Expr.name.prefix() and pl.exclude() to rename the columns.

Do this for each column separately and then

pl.concat() resulting dataframes.

pl.concat([
    df_example
    .pivot(
        index="DATE", values=col, on=col, 
        aggregate_function=pl.element().drop_nulls().is_not_null().first()
    )
    .drop('null')
    .select(
        pl.col("DATE"),
        pl.exclude("DATE").name.prefix(f"{col}_")
    )
    for col in df_example.columns if col != "DATE"
], how="align")

shape: (3, 5)
┌────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────┬──────┐
│ DATE       ┆ A_option1 ┆ A_option2 ┆ B_YES ┆ B_NO │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str        ┆ bool      ┆ bool      ┆ bool  ┆ bool │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 2024-11-11 ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null  ┆ null │
│ 2024-11-12 ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true  ┆ null │
│ 2024-11-13 ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null  ┆ true │
└────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────┴──────┘

alternatively

pl.DataFrame.unpivot() to convert columns to rows.
pl.DataFrame.unique() to drop duplicate empty rows.
pl.DataFrame.pivot() to pivot it back.

(
    df_example
    .unpivot(index="DATE")
    .select(pl.col.DATE, value = pl.col.variable + "_" + pl.col.value)
    .unique(maintain_order=True)
    .pivot(
        index="DATE", on="value", values="value",
        aggregate_function=pl.element().is_not_null().any()
    )
    .drop("null")
)

shape: (3, 5)
┌────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────┬──────┐
│ DATE       ┆ A_option1 ┆ A_option2 ┆ B_YES ┆ B_NO │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str        ┆ bool      ┆ bool      ┆ bool  ┆ bool │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 2024-11-11 ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null  ┆ null │
│ 2024-11-12 ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true  ┆ null │
│ 2024-11-13 ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null  ┆ true │
└────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────┴──────┘

